# Why am I getting json on rails index.html.erb bottom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have rails 4.2.6 installed, I have been getting json for every posts on index, below html display.. it's been on every project I do.. I do not know what to do..  please help me.. Thanks.

[image: index.html.erb]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please include code in your post, otherwise it will be very difficult for developers to help you.

Comment: @Amulya, does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not actually `json`, its the `jobs` array which you're looping through in your `index.html.erb`. You must have something similar in your template.

```
<%= @jobs.each do |job| %> <!-- Note '=' after <% -->
  <!-- display fields -->
<% end %>
```

In `erb`, everything between `<%=... %>` is evaluated and displayed as `html` while the code inside `<% ... %>` is just evaluated. Since you have `<%= @jobs...%>`, `@jobs` array is displayed once the loop gets over. To fix this, just remove the "=" in the beginning of your loop.

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %> <!-- this time we're just looping @jobs, not displaying it -->
  <!-- display fields -->
<% end %>
```